# Fastest way of creating a list through iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, optimization, numpy

I recently created a script to create a Dragon Curve, and managed to optimize the code quite a bit. 
Basically, i start by generating a list of rules, looking something like `[1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]`, where 1 represents a right turn, and -1 represents a left turn. This goes very fast with numpy arrays.

More on the dragon curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve

However, now i want to create a curve in the plane using this list. Basically: pick a point (x, y), and a direction (east), walk one step, and turn 90 degrees right or left depending on the current element in the list, which we loop over. We also take an extra step at the end, but that shouldn't matter to the question.

Let's say that our starting position is (100, 100), we start going east, and the list is `[1, 1, -1]`. Then we should get `[(100, 100), (101, 100), (101, 101), (101, 101), (100, 101), (100, 102)]`, which gives us the second iteration of the dragon curve.

Currently I'm using the following code to generate the sequence of points:

```
pos = [100, 100]
ang = math.pi/2
for i in dragon + [0]:
    pos.extend([pos[-2]+math.cos(ang), pos[-1]+math.sin(ang)])
    ang += i*math.pi/2
```

where `dragon` is the previously generated list, e.g. `[1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]`. I add [0] to take an extra step at the end. For 19 iterations my script outputs:

```
array of length 1048575 completed in 0.00567 seconds
dragon created in 2.82039 seconds
dragon drawn in 0.01462 seconds
image saved in 0.01229 seconds
```

We can clearly see that the code above is the most time-comsuming.
Is there a faster way to generate all these points from the list we previously generated?

Comment: Just because it's time consuming doesn't mean it's slow.

Comment: You could use a lookup table instead of calling `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: The .extend is probably the expensive operation there, I would suggest using a different data type if the performance there is important.

Comment: a slight optimization would be declaring math.cos etc.. outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy can do this as well, quite effeciently! Using the lookup table from Peter Wood's answer we can write for the x-direction:

```
x0 = 100
directions = np.cumsum(2 - dragon) % 4
dx = np.take([0, -1, 0, 1], directions)
x = np.cumsum(np.r_[x0, dx])
```

The `2 - dragon` is to get rid of negative values before taking the modulus.

Comment: With some configuring I got this working beautifully, a lot faster than the previous solution. However, this gives me a problem when I later want to draw the set of points to an image, and I have to use `positions.tolist()`, which consumes a bit of time. Still a lot faster though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As the results of `sin` and `cos` are zero, one, or minus one, and cyclic, you can look them up, modulo four:

```
pos = [100, 100]
direction = 0

east_west_lookup = [0, -1, 0, 1]
north_south_lookup = [1, 0, -1, 0]

for i in dragon + [0]:
    east_west_step = east_west_lookup[direction % 4]
    north_south_step = north_south_lookup[direction % 4]
    pos.extend([pos[-2] + east_west_step,
                pos[-1] + north_south_step])
    direction += i
```

Comment: using a numpy array rather than list for lookup should be a little faster too no?

Comment: Just implementing this made the program about 5-6 times faster, thanks a lot! numpy was really slow, when I used `e_w_lookup = numpy.array([0, -1, 0, 1])`. Maybe I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: Just to note I checked to see whether it produces `[(100, 100), (101, 100), (101, 101), (101, 101), (100, 101), (100, 102)]` but it doesn't. I don't have time to look at it now, but will look later tonight.

Comment: Actually, since i later write to an image, which requires the positions to not be in tuples, your solution was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using a dictionary lookup, I think it's more suitable to use a `tuple` to indicate your position and a `list` to represent the entire path.

I don't have your results, so make sure the `face_dict` is set up properly.

```
dragon = [1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
# format: old-direction -> (add-to-x, add-to-y, new-direction)
# using a list would be faster, but I don't have time to think about it :)
face_dict = {
    "EAST": {-1: (1, 0, "NORTH"), 1: (1, 0, "SOUTH")},
    "SOUTH": {-1: (0, -1, "EAST"), 1: (0, -1, "WEST")},
    "WEST": {-1: (1, 0, "SOUTH"), 1: (1, 0, "NORTH")},
    "NORTH": {-1: (0, 1, "WEST"), 1: (0, 1, "EAST")}
}

# indicate a position using a tuple, a tuple represents a single location
# while a list is suitable to represent a path
pos = (100, 100)
def make_path(directions, start_pos):
    # create empty path with starting position
    path = [None] * len(dragon)
    path[0] = start_pos

    # this is the current state, which is stored in the list after every step.
    current_pos = start_pos
    # this is where we're facing right now
    face = "EAST"
    # each iteration fills a single step in the semi-empty path
    for index, direction in enumerate(directions):
        move = face_dict[face][direction]
        current_pos = (current_pos[0] + move[0], current_pos[1] + move[1])
        face = move[2]
        path[index] = current_pos
    return path
```

**note:** Combining [Peter Wood's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863868/948550) can optimize the lookup on each iteration.

Comment: I'll try implementing this, will post results.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement, but that saves 10-15% time on my system, is to not calculate `math.pi/2` every time. It is not as fast as Peter Wood's solution, but might be useful in case you decide to open the `dragon` list to values other than 0, 1, and -1.

```
pos = [100, 100]
ang = math.pi/2
turn = ang
for i in dragon + [0]:
    pos.extend([pos[-2]+math.cos(ang), pos[-1]+math.sin(ang)])
    ang += i*turn
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try preallocating the space in the list, then remove the `extend` call completely. Something like this (untested):

```
pos = [100] * len(dragon)*2 + 4
ang = math.pi / 2
for idx, i in enumerate(dragon + [0]):
    start = idx*2
    pos[start+2] = pos[start]+math.cos(ang)
    pos[start+3] = pos[start+1]+math.sin(ang)
    ang += i * math.pi / 2
```